# How to interpret the phrase 師匠をつけるほど?

Tags: meaning

This is a passage from NHK's 歴史秘話ヒストリア about Oda Nobunaga performing Noh before the Battle of Okehazama:

> 信長は**師匠をつけるほど**舞いに熱を入れていましたが
>   なぜか「敦盛一種類しか舞わなかった」と記されています。

From the [dictionary](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/147339/meaning/m0u/) the only usage of をつける with a person seems to be:

> ３ ㋒人をそばに置く。そばにいさせて世話をさせる。「ボディーガードを―・ける」

But that doesn't translate go "Nobunaga put the efforts as he was performing in front of a master", imho.

And the phrase meaning seems more like Nobunaga was achieving the performance level of a master. But it's not に着ける.

It also doesn't seem to be a set phrase for performing arts - Google returns only the old transcript of the very TV programme.

---

How to interpret the phrase 師匠をつけるほど here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Formula: "Ａ ほど Ｂ" ≈ "so B that A; B to the extent that A"

(A): "師匠をつける"  ≈ "get (himself) a master instructor"

(B): "舞いに熱を入れていました" ≈ "was passionate about Mai/dancing"

Thus: "信長は師匠をつけるほど舞いに熱を入れていました" ≈ "Nobunaga was very passionate about Mai/dancing, to the extent that he got himself a master instructer (to teach him)"

Answer (score 1):

This つける means what the dictionary says but it doesn't mean "in front of".

It means "to make someone be with someone". So 師匠をつける means "to make a master be with him". This means "to learn from a master(or take a master.)"

So 師匠をつけるほど熱心に means "as eager as he learned from a master(or took a master.).